# Python- PPTX Add_Chart 'Slideplaceholder" object as no attribute 'insert_chart

Tags: python, charts, powerpoint, placeholder, python-pptx

I am trying to insert a chart into a placeholder on a slide. I have tried everything and every variation of code ... any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_Chart_Type

prs=Presentation('Test.pptx')
slide=prs.slides.add_slides(pro.slide_layouts[8])

placeholder=slide.placeholders[1]
placeholder.name
placeholder.placeholder_format.type

chart_data=ChartData()
chart_data.categories=['Yes','No'}
chart_data.add_series('Series 1',(42,44))

graphic_frame = placeholder.insert_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.PIE, chart_data)
chart= graphic_frame.chart
chart.chart_type
```

My slide placeholder is correct, I have already verified that

I get the error that 'Slideplaceholder' object has no attribute 'insert_chart'

any help would be much appreciated but I tried many different things

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the placeholder you've got is 'ChartPlaceholder' or not!